# angular 2 two way binding fail on bootstrap 3 shown.bs.tab event

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components, two-way-binding

angular 2/4 two way binding failed when changes happened in shown.bs.tab event (bootstrap 3 event).

I am new to angular 2/4. Is it a bug?

http://plnkr.co/edit/jZJ64VhVB6yhAzVblJMk

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li role="presentation" class="active">
                <a class="chart-ind" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">h1</a></li>
            <li role="presentation">
                <a class="chart-ind" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">h2</a></li>
            <li role="presentation">
        </ul>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li role="presentation" class="active">
                <a class="chart-ind1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">h3</a></li>
            <li role="presentation">
                <a class="chart-ind1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">h4</a></li>
            <li role="presentation">
        </ul>
        <p id="prevname"></p>
        <p id="aftername"></p>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
    ngAfterViewInit(){
        $('a.chart-ind').on('click', this.tabChange.bind(this));
        $('a.chart-ind1').on('shown.bs.tab',this.tabChange.bind(this));
    }
    tabChange(e) : void{
      $('#prevname').text(this.name);
      this.name = $(e.target).text();
      $('#aftername').text(this.name);

    }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

(All tabs share same callback, and h1,h2 use click, h3,h4 use shown.bs.tab)